# Get different values from potentiometer even not touching

Tags: raspbian, hardware, analog-to-digital, mcp3008

I have a potentiometer that is used to adjust volume level along with MCP3008 but even if I don't touch it, its values are going and coming as following.

```
Press Ctrl-C to quit...
Channel 0 minus 1: 546
Channel 0 minus 1: 531
Channel 0 minus 1: 557
Channel 0 minus 1: 536
Channel 0 minus 1: 537
Channel 0 minus 1: 552
Channel 0 minus 1: 531
Channel 0 minus 1: 556
Channel 0 minus 1: 535
Channel 0 minus 1: 535
Channel 0 minus 1: 545
Channel 0 minus 1: 528
Channel 0 minus 1: 555
Channel 0 minus 1: 528
Channel 0 minus 1: 553
```

But I don't want it to change when I'm not adjusting it. As a solution I make a range in which if the range difference greater than 10, do alteration. But If I do that, volume adjusting is immediately going down or up not slowly(gradually). How can I solve it? I checked that it has ground connection well.

Code:

```
# Simple example of reading the MCP3008 analog input channels using its
# differential mode.  Will print the difference of channel 0 and 1.
# Author: Tony DiCola
# License: Public Domain
import time

# Import SPI library (for hardware SPI) and MCP3008 library.
import Adafruit_GPIO.SPI as SPI
import Adafruit_MCP3008


# Software SPI configuration:
CLK  = 18
MISO = 23
MOSI = 24
CS   = 25
mcp = Adafruit_MCP3008.MCP3008(clk=CLK, cs=CS, miso=MISO, mosi=MOSI)

# Hardware SPI configuration:
#SPI_PORT   = 0
#SPI_DEVICE = 0
#mcp = Adafruit_MCP3008.MCP3008(spi=SPI.SpiDev(SPI_PORT, SPI_DEVICE))

print('Press Ctrl-C to quit...')
while True:
    # Grab the difference between channel 0 and 1 (i.e. channel 0 minus 1).
    # Note you can specify any value in 0-7 to grab other differences:
    #  - 0: Return channel 0 minus channel 1
    #  - 1: Return channel 1 minus channel 0
    #  - 2: Return channel 2 minus channel 3
    #  - 3: Return channel 3 minus channel 2
    #  - 4: Return channel 4 minus channel 5
    #  - 5: Return channel 5 minus channel 4
    #  - 6: Return channel 6 minus channel 7
    #  - 7: Return channel 7 minus channel 6
    value = mcp.read_adc_difference(0)
    print('Channel 0 minus 1: {0}'.format(value))
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: please post a schematic or a wiring diagram

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have noise in your signal, and you should find out where that noise comes from. The first thing I would check is whether you actually need diff mode, since that picks up noise on two channels instead of one. Unless you have your reasons, switch to single-channel mode.

Another solution is to filter out the noise. The easiest option I can think of is to add a low-pass filter. Pick a capacitor in 10-100 μF range and a resistor in 10-100 kΩ range and see if that helps.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is normal - analog devices are not precise, you can expect some variance even when still.

However you can deal with this in software. I'd recommend using the [gpiozero](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/) library which has an [MCP3008](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_spi.html#gpiozero.MCP3008) class and normalises readings on a 0 to 1 scale:

```
from gpiozero import MCP3008

adc = MCP3008(channel=0)

for value in adc.values:
    print(value)
```

You can combine it with gpiozero's [`smoothed`](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_tools.html#gpiozero.tools.smoothed) function which will smoothen out your values by providing the mean of every 5 readings:

```
from gpiozero import MCP3008
from gpiozero.tools import smoothed

adc = MCP3008(channel=0)

for value in smoothed(adc.values, 5):
    print(value)
```